# Install brunch on Mac

Tags: macos, npm, brunch

I'm trying to install brunch on my Macbook. I type in

```
npm install -g brunch
```

and it eventually outputs

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "brunch"
npm ERR! node v6.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/aryaman.arora/npm-debug.log
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run command with super user permissions:

`sudo npm install -g brunch`

Note: this requires root password.

Or you can fix npm's permissions using [this guide](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions).

Comment: I tried that already, I also tried it with root access. I'll check out the guide.